# Why does Laravel API Resource data come this way?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm writing an API Resource. I think it's about **OOP**. In the first code, the `fullName` field is empty, more precisely, only `last_name` comes. But in the second code it works exactly as I wanted it. What is the reason of this?

**FİRST**

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'user_id'       => $this->id,
            'email'         => $this->email,
            'description'   => $this->description,
            'first_name'    => $this->first_name,
            'last_name'     => $this->last_name,
            'full_name'     => $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->last_name,
        ];
    }
```

**SECOND**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $firstName = $this->first_name;
    $lastName  = $this->last_name;
    $fullName  = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;
    return [
        'user_id'       => $this->id,
        'email'         => $this->email,
        'description'   => $this->description,
        'first_name'    => $this->first_name,
        'last_name'     => $this->last_name,
        'full_name'     => $fullName,
    ];
}
```

Comment: what is the name of the model property? `first_name`, `firstname` or `firstName`?

Comment: It was like first_name, I spelled it wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `$this->firstname` in the first one. It should be `$this->first_name`. So it should look like this:

`'full_name' => $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name,`

Comment: I guess I couldn't see it because I just woke up, it's like a joke :) Thank you, man.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes to look at the code.

Comment: Absolutely I agree.